# R - XML of natural language corpus into dataframe

Tags: xml, r, nlp

I am handling an XML file in R using the XML package. My final goal is to create a dataframe containing the following information.

```
LUWPOS LUWDictionaryForm LUWLemma OrthographicTranscription PhoneticTranscription PlainOrthographicTranscription Devoiced MoraID　ToneClass MoraID
動詞 ダイスル 題する 題し ダイシ 題し 1 3 accent 1
```

LUWPOS, LUWDictionaryForm, LUWLemma are atts of the LUW node. OrthographicTranscription, PhoneticTranscriptio, PlainOrthographicTranscription are in the SUW, daughter of LUW. Devoiced is in the Phone node, a descendant of SUW. MoraID is a att of the Mora node, which is a grandmother of Phone. ToneClass is a attribute of the node XJToBILabelTone, which is a descendant of Phone. The second MoraID is the closest ancestor of XJToBILabelTone containing the Toneclass=accent. 
Not even all Phone nodes contain the att Devoiced. In this case, I don't need the first MoraID. When XJToBILabelTone does not contain ToneClass="accent", I don't need the second MoraID either.

So far, I could do the following:

```
doc= xmlInternalTreeParse(file="A01F0122.xml") #opens the file
    luw <- xpathSApply(doc, "//LUW", xmlAttrs) #extracts the attributes of the node LUW
    df <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind, luw)) #creates the dataframe
```

It gave me the following output.

```
LUWID LUWPOS IsNewLine LineID LUWDictionaryForm     LUWLemma LUWMiscPOSInfo1
19     2   名詞         1    002          ホンジツ         本日               2
20     3   名詞         1    003    ハッピョウシャ       発表者               3
21     4   助詞         0    003                ノ           の          格助詞
22     5   名詞         1    004              ××××           ××        固有名詞
23     6   名詞         1    005        キュウヨウ         急用               6
24     7   助詞         0    005      ニツキマシテ につきまして          格助詞
25     1   名詞         1    001          ケッセキ         欠席               1
26     2 助動詞         0    001      デゴザイマス でございます          連用形
27     3   助詞         0    001                テ           て        接続助詞
28     4   名詞         1    002            カワリ       代わり               4
29     5   助詞         0    002                ニ           に          格助詞
30     6 代名詞         1    003          ワタクシ           私               6
```

It contains some of the information I want, but I don't know how to get the descendants of LUW.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Talk TalkID="A01F0122" SpeakerID="463" SpeakerBirthPlace="神奈川県" SpeakerBirthGeneration="70to74" SpeakerSex="女">
  <TalkComment>
    <Comment CommentStrings="講演ID:A01F0122"/>
    <Comment CommentStrings=""/>
    <Comment CommentStrings=""/>
  </TalkComment>
  <IPU IPUID="0001" IPUStartTime="00000.312" IPUEndTime="00001.973" Channel="L">
    <LUW LUWID="9" LUWPOS="動詞" IsNewLine="1" LineID="006" LUWDictionaryForm="ダイスル" LUWLemma="題する" LUWConjugateType="サ行変格" LUWConjugateForm="連用形">
      <SUW SUWID="1" ColumnID="001" SUWDictionaryForm="ダイスル" SUWLemma="題する" SUWConjugateForm="連用形" SUWConjugateType="サ行変格" SUWConjugateForm2="連用形" SUWConjugateType2="サ行変格" SUWPOS="動詞" OrthographicTranscription="題し" PhoneticTranscription="ダイシ" PlainOrthographicTranscription="題し" APID="7" Dep_BunsetsuUnitID="6" Dep_ModifieeBunsetsuUnitID="7">
        <TransSUW TransSUWID="1">
          <Mora MoraEntity="ダ" MoraID="1" PerceivedAcc="1">
            <Phoneme PhonemeEntity="d" PhonemeID="1">
              <Phone PhoneID="1" PhoneEntity="SclS" PhoneClass="others" PhoneStartTime="6.188682" PhoneEndTime="6.19458"/>
              <Phone PhoneID="2" PhoneEntity="d" PhoneClass="consonant" PhoneStartTime="6.19458" PhoneEndTime="6.207031"/>
            </Phoneme>
            <Phoneme PhonemeEntity="a" PhonemeID="2">
              <Phone PhoneID="1" PhoneEntity="a" PhoneClass="vowel" PhoneStartTime="6.207031" PhoneEndTime="6.317124">
                <XJToBILabelTone Time="6.212447" F0="209.865" ToneClass="IBT">%L</XJToBILabelTone>
                <XJToBILabelTone Time="6.275146" F0="195.496" ToneClass="accent">A</XJToBILabelTone>
              </Phone>
            </Phoneme>
          </Mora>
          <Mora MoraEntity="イ" MoraID="2">
            <Phoneme PhonemeEntity="i" PhonemeID="1">
              <Phone PhoneID="1" PhoneEntity="i" PhoneClass="vowel" PhoneStartTime="6.317124" PhoneEndTime="6.361029"/>
            </Phoneme>
          </Mora>
          <Mora MoraEntity="シ" MoraID="3">
            <Phoneme PhonemeEntity="sj" PhonemeID="1">
              <Phone PhoneID="1" PhoneEntity="sj" PhoneClass="consonant" PhoneStartTime="6.361029" PhoneEndTime="6.406245" EndTimeUncertain="1"/>
            </Phoneme>
            <Phoneme PhonemeEntity="i" PhonemeID="2">
              <Phone PhoneID="1" PhoneEntity="i" PhoneClass="vowel" Devoiced="1" PhoneStartTime="6.406245" PhoneEndTime="6.451461" StartTimeUncertain="1">
                <XJToBILabelWord Time="6.451461" PerceivedAccPos="1">daisji</XJToBILabelWord>
                <XJToBILabelBreak Time="6.451461">1</XJToBILabelBreak>
              </Phone>
            </Phoneme>
          </Mora>
        </TransSUW>
      </SUW>
    </LUW>
    <LUW LUWID="10" LUWPOS="助詞" IsNewLine="0" LineID="006" LUWDictionaryForm="テ" LUWLemma="て" LUWMiscPOSInfo1="接続助詞">
      <SUW SUWID="1" ColumnID="005" SUWDictionaryForm="テ" SUWLemma="て" SUWMiscPOSInfo1="接続助詞" SUWPOS="助詞" OrthographicTranscription="て" PhoneticTranscription="テ" PlainOrthographicTranscription="て" APID="7">
        <TransSUW TransSUWID="1">
          <Mora MoraEntity="テ" MoraID="1">
            <Phoneme PhonemeEntity="t" PhonemeID="1">
              <Phone PhoneID="1" PhoneEntity="SclS" PhoneClass="others" PhoneStartTime="6.451461" PhoneEndTime="6.484228">
                <XJToBILabelTone Time="6.451887" ToneClass="LTBPM" F0Uncertain="1">L%</XJToBILabelTone>
              </Phone>
              <Phone PhoneID="2" PhoneEntity="t" PhoneClass="consonant" PhoneStartTime="6.484228" PhoneEndTime="6.497334"/>
            </Phoneme>
            <Phoneme PhonemeEntity="e" PhonemeID="2">
              <Phone PhoneID="1" PhoneEntity="e" PhoneClass="vowel" PhoneStartTime="6.497334" PhoneEndTime="6.565485">
                <XJToBILabelTone Time="6.536170" F0="245.046" ToneClass="Pointer">pH</XJToBILabelTone>
                <XJToBILabelWord Time="6.565485" PerceivedAccPos="0">te</XJToBILabelWord>
                <XJToBILabelBreak Time="6.565485">1</XJToBILabelBreak>
              </Phone>
            </Phoneme>
          </Mora>
        </TransSUW>
      </SUW>
    </LUW>
  </IPU>
</Talk>
```

Answer (score 1):

(This is not a solution but some guidance for one way to proceed. Pasting code in comments is less than optimal in SO)

You should consider going the list manipulation route vs the XML paths route.

```
# get the XML doc as a list of nested lists
doc.list <- xmlToList(doc)
# inspect it
str(doc.list)

# get the LUW nested list to make it easier to process
luw.list <- dl$IPU$LUW
# inspect it
str(luw.list)

# look at the attributes
str(luw.list$.attrs)

# inspect the SUM node
str(luw.list$SUW)
```

Once you get a feel for the structure you should be able to use various `*apply` or `dply` functions to extract what you need.